# Vertically Align Text with Logo

Tags: html, css, angular, sass

I am trying to vertically align an icon from Material Design icons with some text for my web app. However, the logo and text are not perfectly vertically align. As shown below:

[image]

How can I fix this? The code is as follows:

**HTML**:

```
<div class="categoryRow">
  <div class="category">
    <mat-icon aria-hidden="false" aria-label="Example book icon" class="logo">book</mat-icon>
    <h1 class="categoryLabel">English</h1>
  </div>

</div>
```

**SCSS**:

```
.categoryRow{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;

  .category{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    &:hover{
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  }

}
```

I checked the _icon-theme.css file, and found the following code:

```
@mixin mat-icon-color($config-or-theme) {
  $config: mat-get-color-config($config-or-theme);
  $primary: map-get($config, primary);
  $accent: map-get($config, accent);
  $warn: map-get($config, warn);
  $background: map-get($config, background);
  $foreground: map-get($config, foreground);

  .mat-icon {
    &.mat-primary {
      color: mat-color($primary, text);
    }

    &.mat-accent {
      color: mat-color($accent, text);
    }

    &.mat-warn {
      color: mat-color($warn, text);
    }
  }
}

@mixin mat-icon-typography($config-or-theme) {}

@mixin _mat-icon-density($config-or-theme) {}

@mixin mat-icon-theme($theme-or-color-config) {
  $theme: _mat-legacy-get-theme($theme-or-color-config);
  @include _mat-check-duplicate-theme-styles($theme, 'mat-icon') {
    $color: mat-get-color-config($theme);
    $density: mat-get-density-config($theme);
    $typography: mat-get-typography-config($theme);

    @if $color != null {
      @include mat-icon-color($color);
    }
    @if $density != null {
      @include _mat-icon-density($density);
    }
    @if $typography != null {
      @include mat-icon-typography($typography);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is going to be hard to solve if you don't provide a working example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Check for padding on your `<mat-icon>` and `.categoryLabel`. Google old style had some negative space in their icons. New style they made their icons (containers) flexbox layout with `justify-content,align-content,align-items: center`. Always dead center.... And what @Nico Shultz said: post a [reprex]!

Comment: You have `flex-direction: column;` to `.category`. Try to write in the same class - `justify-content: center;`

Comment: @NicoShultz Alright! I simplified the code to make it an MRE.

Comment: @RenevanderLende I updated the code to be more simplifed. Would this be considered MRE?

Comment: Well the problem is we can't load the icon you use so we will never know how it actualy placed

Comment: @NicoShultz Oh. I understand. Currently I am using an Angular project with the mat-icon module, but you should be able to replicate it using an svg or png of the logo at this link:
https://material.io/resources/icons/?search=book&icon=book&style=baseline

Comment: Actually, any img,svg,character would do, but it is the `<mat-icon>` CSS we need to see as the icon does not align properly (it seems)... Add `.category { justify-content: center }` maybe?

Comment: like @RenevanderLende said its the `mat-icon` created a replicate here: https://jsfiddle.net/g71frbsu/ where it works with your css

Comment: @ NicoShultz @RenevanderLende I checked node_modules folder for the icon directory, and I found a css file called _icon_theme.css. The post is updated with the content inside the file.